# writedlm a matrix of Bool as a 0,1 matrix

Tags: julia

I have a matrix of `Bool` values, for example

```
x = bitrand(2,3)
```

If I try to save this to a file:

```
writedlm("mat.txt", x)
```

I get a matrix of `true` and `false`. I would like to get instead a matrix of `0` and `1` (where 0 replaces false and 1 replaces true). Is there a simple way to do this, perhaps by some options in `writedlm`, without writing the file line by line myself?

Comment: Try `1*x`, it gets the numerical version (perhaps not super memory/time efficient, but good enough for non "big data" stuff). `0x1*x` will get a UInt8 more memory compact (but probably slower).

Comment: @DanGetz You should post that as an answer. It's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `1*x`, it gets the numerical version (perhaps not super memory/time efficient, but good enough for non "big data" stuff). `0x1*x` will get a UInt8 - more memory compact (but probably slower).

Answer (score 5):

```
writedlm("mat.txt", map(Int8,x))
```

Takes each element of `x` and converts it to an integer using the `Int8` function/constructor.

You could also use other integer types but `Int8` is more memory efficient than for example `Int64`.

Comment: You can also use `Int8` which would achieve the same thing, yet is much more memory efficient. Tried it with 800x800 matrix and `Int64` used 4.8MB while `Int8` used only 0.6MB.

Comment: This involves loading a full copy of the converted matrix into memory. I'm doing this `writedlm` inside a loop, so I think the performance impact is too much.

Comment: Is there a lazy version of `map`? I'm googling but cannot find any.

Comment: There's [Lazy.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/Lazy.jl) and [LazySequences.jl](https://github.com/dcjones/LazySequences.jl). If these don't work out for you, you might as well write your [own output function](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/networking-and-streams/)

Comment: The IO (input/output) will probably be much slower than the map. You can test this with the built-in profiler in Julia.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders That's a good point. But I am still worried about memory.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that is slightly faster is to *copy* the array to `UInt8` on the fly as `Array{UInt8, ndims(x)}(x)`, rather than applying `map`:

```
>>> x = bitrand(100,100)
>>> a = map(UInt8, x)
>>> b = Array{UInt8, ndims(x)}(x)
>>> all(a .== b)
true
```

I ran quick some tests and it is sightly faster the larger the matrices are (at least in my computer).

```
for i in [10, 100, 1_000, 10_000]
    x = bitrand(i,i)
    println("$i x $i")
    @time map(UInt8, x)
    @time Array{UInt8, ndims(x)}(x)
end
```

Outputs:

```
10 x 10
  0.000002 seconds (2 allocations: 208 bytes)
  0.000006 seconds (2 allocations: 208 bytes)
100 x 100
  0.000053 seconds (2 allocations: 9.891 KB)
  0.000018 seconds (2 allocations: 9.891 KB)
1000 x 1000
  0.001945 seconds (5 allocations: 976.703 KB)
  0.001490 seconds (5 allocations: 976.703 KB)
10000 x 10000
  0.224491 seconds (5 allocations: 95.368 MB)
  0.117774 seconds (5 allocations: 95.368 MB)
```

Comment: I usually understand the word "cast" as meaning what in Julia is called `reinterpret`, i.e. look at the same bits in memory in a different way. Here you are, however, again creating a *new* matrix.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders I do agree that *cast* shouldn't create a copy, maybe is not the best word here (reworded to *copy*). `reinterpret(UInt8, x)` is the best solution if `x` is an `Array{Bool}`, however, `bitrand` returns a `BitArray` which is not supported by `reinterpret`.